# TableView's indexPathsForVisibleRows returns data for old screen orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screen-orientation

I am dynamically changing annotations on the map based on the tableview's items that are visible (works ok when user scrolls in tableview). When the screen rotation changes, i call `indexPathsForVisibleRows` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to show the pins for the visible tableviews, but `indexPathsForVisibleRows` doesn't return data for new orientation.

When and where should i call `indexPathsForVisibleRows` to get the correct data for new `orientation`?

Answer (score 1):

You should call it in

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

*Sent to the view controller after the user interface rotates.*

Method

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

*Sent to the view controller before performing a one-step user interface rotation.*

Comment: Putting indexPathsForVisibleRows in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation still returns visible rows for portrait orientation (more than in landscape of course). What could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't suggest anything else.